# Starting hadoop - command not found

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I have zero experience in hadoop and trying to set up hadoop in ec2 environment. After formatted the filesystem, I tried to start hadoop and it keeps saying command not found.

I think I have tried every advice I found on stackoverflow previous questions/answers.

Here is the line I am having trouble with:

```
[root@ip-172-31-22-92 ~]# start-hadoop.sh
-bash: start-hadoop.sh: command not found
```

I have tried all the following commands (which I found on previous answers)

```
[root@ip-172-31-22-92 ~]# hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
-bash: hadoop-daemon.sh: command not found

[root@ip-172-31-22-92 ~]# ./start-all.sh
-bash: ./start-all.sh: No such file or directory

[root@ip-172-31-22-92 ~]# cd /usr/local/hadoop/
-bash: cd: /usr/local/hadoop/: No such file or directory
```

Honestly, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Plus, I am doing this as root...is this right? it seems like I should be in user...?! (discard this question if i just sounded dumber)

Comment: so which document did you follow? do you have unix/linux knowledge to check if these files are exist or not, for example, with command: `ls -l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you have downloaded/installed the hadoop package or not, so let me walk you through the process of it briefly:

1. Download the latest package using wget:

   ```
   wget http://apache.cs.utah.edu/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the package relative to where you have downloaded it:

   ```
   tar xzf hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz
   ```
3. change the dir into the extracted directory

   ```
   cd hadoop-2.7.1
   ```
4. Now you would be able to find or start the hadoop daemons using:

   ```
   sbin/start-all.sh
   ```

You can find the script's you are trying to use in the extracted dir's  (`hadoop-2.7.1`) `sbin` folder.

Make sure you follow the proper documentation to get it completed properly, because I haven't really covered installing Java or configuring hadoop which are extensively covered in the following documentation link:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Answer (score 0):

The scripts in this repository could help you to understand the steps to install hadoop. https://github.com/lalosam/EasyHadoop (hadoop.sh). You could try to download it and execute it. The script should download the hadoop library and confgure it as pseudo cluster. `start-hadoop` and `stop-hadoop` scripts start and stop all the services required for hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

First You may have to add your HADOOP_HOME variable in .bashrc file .
Ex:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/bigdata/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME:/usr/local/bigdata/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Then open a new session and execute `./start-all.sh`